# how to create a complex record in latin pig when writing with avro schema

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following relation in latin pig and I need to store it into a avro-schema file:

```
    data = load 'data.dat' as (a: long, b: chararray, c: long);
...
    STORE data INTO 'file' USING avroStorage();
```

But I need the data to be in the format:

```
Record 1:
{
  "a" : {
    "long" : 2
  },
  "complex" : {
      "b" : {
        "string" : "abc"
      },
      "c" : {
        "long" : 3
      }
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code to see how it's translated to avro schema but try to start with this code

```
data = load 'data.dat' as (a: long, b: chararray, c: long);    
transformed = foreach data generate a, TOTUPLE(b, c);        
STORE transformed INTO 'file' USING avroStorage();
```

Documentation for TOTUPLE - http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#totuple